# How can I Implement a Horizontal Scroll Bar for a JSF BarChart with PrimeFaces?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I find myself immersed in a project involving JSF technology in synergy with the PrimeFaces library, and I have encountered a challenge worthy of consideration. I need guidance on the methodology to be adopted for implementing a horizontal scroll bar in my BarChart. This need arises due to the possibility of an overload of data coming from the backend layer, such that the full visibility of this data requires the presence of the mentioned scroll bar.

XHTML:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <div class="dashboardPercentualEntregasPorBase-card rounded">
    
            <p:barChart model="#{MB.percentualEntregaPorBase}" 
                        styleClass="percentual-de-entregas"
                        style="width: 100%; height: 250px;" />

    </div>



</ui:composition>
```

CSS:

```
.dashboardPercentualEntregasPorBase-card{
    
    width: 98%;
    height: 100%;

    box-shadow: 3px 7px 9px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.64);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 7px 9px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.64);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 7px 9px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.64);
}
.percentual-de-entregas{
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

From the Java code, the values initialized in the BarChartModel below are mocked for front-end testing purposes. I've placed them here in case the scrollbar is a backend attribute. That's the report.

```
   private void createPercentualEntregaPorBase() {
        this.percentualEntregaPorBase = new BarChartModel();
        ChartData data = new ChartData();
        
        BarChartDataSet barDataSet = new BarChartDataSet();
        barDataSet.setLabel("Concluidos");
        barDataSet.setBackgroundColor("#08B408");
        barDataSet.setStack("Stack 0");
        List<Number> dataVal = Arrays.asList(45, 68, 84, 58, 57, 48, 86, 60, 94, 45,100,90,80,70,60,50,90, 45, 68, 84, 58, 57, 48, 86, 60, 94, 45,100,90,80,70,60,50,90,100,90,80,70,60,50,90, 50,90,100,90,80,70,60,50,90,50,90,100,90,80,70,60,50,90);
        barDataSet.setData(dataVal);
        
        BarChartDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarChartDataSet();
        barDataSet2.setLabel("Retornos");
        barDataSet2.setBackgroundColor("#FF0000");
        barDataSet2.setStack("Stack 0");
        List<Number> dataVal2 = Arrays.asList(40, 55, 80, 56, 55, 40, 81, 56, 90, 40,80,95,83,74,68,57,80, 40, 55, 80, 56, 55, 40, 81, 56, 90, 40,80,95,83,74,68,57,80, 101,92,81,71,62,51,91);
        barDataSet2.setData(dataVal2);
     
        data.addChartDataSet(barDataSet);
        data.addChartDataSet(barDataSet2);
  
        List<String> labels =  new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
            labels.add("CD " + i);
        }

        data.setLabels(labels);
        this.percentualEntregaPorBase.setData(data);
        
        //Options
        BarChartOptions options = new BarChartOptions();
        CartesianScales cScales = new CartesianScales();
        CartesianLinearAxes linearAxes = new CartesianLinearAxes();
        linearAxes.setStacked(true);    
        cScales.addXAxesData(linearAxes);
        cScales.addYAxesData(linearAxes);
        options.setScales(cScales);
        
        Title title = new Title();
        title.setDisplay(true);
        title.setText("Percentual de entregas por base");
        options.setTitle(title);
        
        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        tooltip.setMode("index");
        tooltip.setIntersect(false);
        options.setTooltip(tooltip);
        Legend legend = new Legend();
        legend.setDisplay(false);
        options.setLegend(legend);

        this.percentualEntregaPorBase.setOptions(options);
    }
```

Here is an image of what we have now, those  little  Scroll pointers does't work.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to wrap the chart in a div and make that scrollable?

Comment: Yes,  but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I was searching for. The width of the model shouldn't be specified using %, and the parent div should be styled with 'overflow-x: auto;'.

```
<div class="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center" 
     style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;">

    <div style="width: max-content;">

        <p:barChart model="#{MB.taxaRetornoEventosBarModel}" 
                    style="height: 400px; width: 1100px;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you wanna go fancy try PrimeFaces ScrollPanel, you can controll CSS of scrollbar then